# Inner Join with restriction if a criteria is met

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have a query where I have to add additional criteria to met the needs.

criteria: *if [dd.DataDefinitionValueText] = "PA" then the query should only display those who have value "B" in [cs.ClientSupporterRemarks].*

I tried to use IF statements in the INNER JOIN but I can't figure it out properly. Do I have to edit the last INNER JOIN or the one before that?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Code:

```
SELECT 
Distinct 
        c.CSName 
        ,dd.DataDefinitionValueText
       ,cs.ClientSupporterIsPrimaryContact
       ,cs.ClientSupporterRemarks
       ,usr.UserEMail
       ,usr.UserName
FROM DB_Analysis a
INNER JOIN [dbo].[DB_Projects] pr ON
       a.AnalysisProjectID = pr.ProjectID
       AND pr.ProjectIsActive = 1
INNER JOIN DB_Clients c on
       c.ClientID = pr.ProjectClientID         
INNER JOIN [dbo].[DB_ClientSupporters] cs ON
       cs.ClientSupporterClientID = c.ClientID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[DB_Users] usr ON
       cs.ClientSupporterUserID = usr.UserID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[DB_DataDefinitions] dd ON
       cs.ClientSupporterRole = dd.DataDefinitionValueID 
       AND dd.DataDefinitionName = 'ClientSupporterRole'
WHERE c.ClientIsActive = 1
```

Comment: But what exactly is your question? Expressing the if in on/where or where to put that test? x inner join y on c is x cross join y where c is y inner join x on c, so it doesn't matter where you put a test in a sequence of inner join ons & where as long as tables are in a join before an on/where. PS For code questions give a [mre]. PS. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition stating "if Foo then Bar" means that when foo is false, the condition is satisfied, and when foo is true (or false), the condition is satisfied when Bar is true, so:

```
if Foo is true then Bar must be true
```

means

```sql
WHERE ( NOT FOO  OR  BAR )
```

For the query in the question, that means:

```sql
WHERE c.ClientIsActive = 1
  AND ( dd.DataDefinitionValueTest <> "PA"
     OR dd.DataDefinitionValueTest IS NULL -- remove if column is NOT NULL
     OR cs.ClientSupporterRemarks = "B" )
```

For the query in the question, you can also add that extra set of conditions to the `dd` JOIN, instead of to the `WHERE` clause, it makes no difference.

```sql
INNER JOIN [dbo].[DB_DataDefinitions] dd
        ON cs.ClientSupporterRole = dd.DataDefinitionValueID 
       AND dd.DataDefinitionName = 'ClientSupporterRole'
       AND ( dd.DataDefinitionValueTest <> "PA"
          OR dd.DataDefinitionValueTest IS NULL -- remove if column is NOT NULL
          OR cs.ClientSupporterRemarks = "B" )
```

Comment: thanks, it worked as of now. But in your Where statement, what happens if "B" is also part of another combination? Let's say "B" can also be in Remarks other than "PA".

Comment: @smartini Your new criteria didn't specify that you cannot show "B" when not "PA", only that when it *is* "PA", only show "B".